# How to make rows in table immutable in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to define a table that contains immutable rows in PostgreSQL? How to prevent modification of rows and allow append/remove only operations?

Comment: The most secure way would be to revoke the `update` privilege on the table.

Comment: you can also create trigger and set new values = old values in some rows